# Export/Import mySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, import, export

I'm looking to implement an Export/Import feature in a WordPress Plug-in. The only scenario that I can think of, is exporting the data after querying the database to some format and then re-reading it (for import) and creating a query with that data.

I'm thinking if there is a shortcut for that. What I want basically is a function to get the SQL query of the data I have in the database and then execute it when importing. This is basically the same function in PHPmyAdmin that exports the database.

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [MySQL's `SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html), specifically the `... INTO OUTFILE` portion.  Couple that with [MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) and you might be in business.